# find and replace content between two words in POM

Tags: python, bash

Need a bash script or python script to find and replace text between two tags?

E.g:

```
<start>text to find and replace with the one I give as input<end>
```

' text to find and replace with the one I give as input' is just an example and it could vary every time.

I want to do something like ./changetxt inputfile.xxx newtext

where changetxt has the script;
inputfile.xxx has the text that needs a change and newtext is what goes into inputfile.xxx

Comment: ok, that is more clear. I only need to know how you would determine what text to change. Is it always between the same tags or do they also vary?

Comment: @RickyA - It is always between the same tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #ajust these to your need
    starttag = "<foo>"
    endtag = "</foo>"

    inputfilename = sys.argv[1]
    outputfilename = inputfilename + ".out"
    replacestr = sys.argv[2]

    #open the inputfile from the first argument
    inputfile = open(inputfilename, 'r')
    #open an outputfile to put the result in
    outputfile = open(outputfilename, 'w')

    #test every line in the file for the starttag
    for line in inputfile:
        if starttag in line and endtag in line:
            #compose a new line with the replaced string
            newline = line[:line.find(starttag) + len(starttag)] + replacestr + line[line.find(endtag):]
            #and write the new line to the outputfile
            outputfile.write(newline)
        else:
            outputfile.write(line)
     outputfile.close()
     inputfile.close()
```

Save this in a replacetext.py file and run as python replacetext.py \path\to\inputfile "I want this text between the tags"

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP means . . .

Comment: @Ricky: I don't think you understood the question right. The text between the tags is only an example.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but since this this question is missing vitals as: where does the input comes from (steam, file). what format is it (str, obj). what should the output be. etc.etc. I just can aswer the replacement part...

Comment: @RickyA - I added more details. I hope my question is more clearer now.

Comment: @RickyA - Thanks a ton! I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for this, from their docs:

> If you set a tag’s .string attribute, the tag’s contents are replaced
>   with the string you give:

```
markup = '<a href="http://example.com/">I linked to <i>example.com</i></a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)

tag = soup.a
tag.string = "New link text."
tag
# <a href="http://example.com/">New link text.</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, but the example is not HTML nor XML